# Output from jstack missing tid and nid information

Tags: java, linux, jstack

I have a Linux box with nearly maxed out CPU utilization.  I used `top` to track down the offending Java process (12462) and underlying threads (12465 and 12466).  I was hoping to run `jstack` and search in the output for 30b1 and 30b2 (the aforementioned threads converted to hex) so I could figure out what Java is doing.

When I ran `jstack` without any flags, it returned the following error:

```
12462: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
```

However, when I ran `jstack -F` the output didn't contain tid or nid information.  Here's an excerpt from the output:

```
Thread 31374: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[], int, int, int) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=79, line=150 (Compiled frame)
 - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=121 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(boolean) @bci=59, line=516 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill() @bci=2, line=501 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.setRequestLineReadTimeout() @bci=90, line=173 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper) @bci=156, line=925 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper, org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketStatus) @bci=149, line=585 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run() @bci=130, line=312 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1145 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=615 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=722 (Interpreted frame)
```

I ran `jstack -F -l` but the command seemed to lock up.

When I ran `jstack -F -m`, I was able to find the decimal threads but the output didn't contain enough of the actual Java stack for me to figure out what it's doing.  Here's another portion of the output:

```
----------------- 12465 -----------------
0x0000003e54889dd0      _wordcopy_fwd_aligned + 0x140
```

What am I missing?  How can I get `jstack` to show me the tid and nid?

Comment: Is there any reason for using the `-F` option?

Comment: I couldn't get `jstack` to return anything without using the `-F` option.  I've updated the post with a bit more information.

Comment: I’m a afraid that’s a limitation of the `-F` option (at least in the current implementation). I can reproduce the behavior, including the hanging when using `-F -l` even on an entirely different architecture like Windows.

Comment: If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.  On a related note, do you know what conditions necessitate the use of `-F`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use -F you cannot get the tid and nid.
I believe that you are jstacking some pid which doesn't belong to you. Try to switch to the user who own the pid before executing jstack. Try the following command

```
sudo -u {user who own the process} jstack -l pid
```